# Mongoose: how to use aggregate and flatten subdocument to list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can i get this result in this situation?

I have one collection named coins

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc8c47f638267be1b00e808"),
    "mintTxid" : "abc371bb13034ed6acf96a39e09b22347f0038002eb8a21493032885ba6b77da",
    "address" : "mokZmpYj3vSqghQaZXZ8AGt1oo1HyidLow",
    "spentTxid" : "fddc7f7c6492e0cf670ff4f96e7aaaeeee3d75c51538a35286b66b6707260b46"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc91d0d638267be1b21c2eb"),
    "mintTxid" : "fddc7f7c6492e0cf670ff4f96e7aaaeeee3d75c51538a35286b66b6707260b46",
    "address" : "mwE7bR8nLF9G1jUY17DzRhdWRrs4fGppvA"
  }
]
```

I used $lookup and joined itself(spentTxid = mintTxid)

```
db.getCollection('coins').aggregate([
    { $match: {'address': 'mokZmpYj3vSqghQaZXZ8AGt1oo1HyidLow'}},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'coins',
            localField: 'spentTxid',
            foreignField: 'mintTxid',
            as: 'spents'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$spents',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    }
])
```

And here is a result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc8c47f638267be1b00e808"),
    "mintTxid" : "abc371bb13034ed6acf96a39e09b22347f0038002eb8a21493032885ba6b77da",
    "address" : "mokZmpYj3vSqghQaZXZ8AGt1oo1HyidLow",
    "spentTxid" : "fddc7f7c6492e0cf670ff4f96e7aaaeeee3d75c51538a35286b66b6707260b46",
    "spents" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc91d0d638267be1b21c2eb"),
        "mintTxid" : "fddc7f7c6492e0cf670ff4f96e7aaaeeee3d75c51538a35286b66b6707260b46",
        "address" : "mwE7bR8nLF9G1jUY17DzRhdWRrs4fGppvA",
    }
}
```

How can i get a result like this? i used $replaceRoot option, But that option return only child.

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc8c47f638267be1b00e808"),
    "mintTxid" : "abc371bb13034ed6acf96a39e09b22347f0038002eb8a21493032885ba6b77da",
    "address" : "mokZmpYj3vSqghQaZXZ8AGt1oo1HyidLow",
    "spentTxid" : "fddc7f7c6492e0cf670ff4f96e7aaaeeee3d75c51538a35286b66b6707260b46",
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc91d0d638267be1b21c2eb"),
    "mintTxid" : "fddc7f7c6492e0cf670ff4f96e7aaaeeee3d75c51538a35286b66b6707260b46",
    "address" : "mwE7bR8nLF9G1jUY17DzRhdWRrs4fGppvA",
  }
]
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After aggregate add below pipeline stages and then try:

```
  {
    $project: {
      array: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              _id: "$$ROOT._id",
              address: "$$ROOT.address",
              mintTxid: "$$ROOT.mintTxid",
              spentTxid: "$$ROOT.spentTxid",

            }
          ],
          [
            "$$ROOT.spents"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$array"
    }
  }
```

1. in project we create a new array in which we push two arrays as per our requirements
2. unwind the array
3. replace root with data in ROOT